# C3P0 connection Pooling issues

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0, connection-timeout

Every night between the hours of 12 am to 4 am the app runs out of connections. We use c3p0 to manage the connection pool. Currently have a maxpoolsize of 20. Its very intriguing that this happens only in the night. Would appreciate if someone could guide me on how can i troubleshoot this. The reason i am stumped is that why does it not happen during the day.

Here are the steps that I have either taken or in the process of taking, I will appreciate if a pro can add further to this.

1. Already looked at the eventViewer logs of the machine where the app is running.
2. Have asked for eventViewer logs of the machine where the db is running
3. Have asked for sqlserver logs during that time
4. Have asked the DBA team to provide information on any jobs that might be running during that time

What else can i do from C3P0 side, I guess I could increase the logging, is configuring C3P0 logging as simple as just adding a logger category in my log4j.xml ? I read somewhere that I could use JMX to monitor connection pooling, would that help ? Anything anyone can tell me more, would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 has some facilities built-in to debug Connection pool exhaustion. please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients